# How to set up LibGDX's fbx-conv on Linux

Tags: shared-libraries, libgdx, dynamic-linking, fbx

I'm trying to get a 3d model from Blender to LibGdx but I need to install fbx-conv, I have made a copy of libfbxsdk.so and put it in usr/lib as the readme suggests but how do I link libfbxsdk.so and libfbxsdk.dynlib?

Answer (score 2):

I just unzip the fbx-conv bundle from the build server (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/fbx-conv/)

and run

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./fbx-conv-lin64
```

if you think you might forget this, just paste it into a text file and make it executable with

```
chmod +x run-fbx.sh
```

(assuming you have called the file run-fbx.sh!)

Comment: I get a segmentation fault

Comment: no one can help you with almost no clues, a seg fault could be caused by many things...

Comment: I actually found out that it is a recurring bug for linux builds, unfortunately. I ended up using wine and the windows build to get around this issue. I wish I had the original working binary that you have haha

Comment: Simpler just to build it yourself if you're having issues

Comment: Except that building it fails too, disappointing all around really. It's funny how the game engine is in Java, platform independent, yet this tool is in c++.